# Reduction of order on a 2nd order LI DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, reduction-of-order-ode

The equation and $y_1(x)$ are $$y_1(x)=x^{\frac{-1}{2}}\cos(x) $$

$$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-\frac{1}{4})y=0$$
Using the formula that solves for $y_2(x)$

(*the one with an integration factor over $y_1(x)$ squared, all inside an integral multiplied by $y_1(x)$*)

We get $$ x^{-1/2}\cos(x) \int \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{x^{1/4}\cos^2(x)}dx $$
Now from here what I thought to do  was to rationalize the integrand. There by making the equation easier for integration.

Just focusing on the integral I got 
$$\int \frac{1}{x^4\sqrt{x} *cos^2(x)} dx$$ 
Now it only seems to me that the integration has only gotten more complicated. Could this be done by parts or u-sub?

Comment: @Moo I know its a lot of work but could you show me the first round of the substituition into (1)'s distribution? (I know where to sub in and all that but it's the alegbra with the exponets thats confusing me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

$$x^2y''+xy'+\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{4}\right)y=0 \tag 1$$

We are also given a solution as

$$y_1(x)=x^{-1/2}\cos(x)$$

Using [*Reduction of Order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order), a second solution is given by

$$y_2(x) = y_1(x) v(x) = x^{-1/2} \cos(x) v(x)$$

The first derivative is

$$y_2'(x) = \frac{\cos (x) v'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{v(x) \cos (x)}{2 x^{3/2}}-\frac{v(x) \sin (x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

The second derivative is

$$y_2''(x) = -\frac{\cos (x) v'(x)}{x^{3/2}}-\frac{2 \sin (x) v'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\cos (x) v''(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{v(x) \sin (x)}{x^{3/2}}+\frac{3 v(x) \cos (x)}{4 x^{5/2}}-\frac{v(x) \cos (x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Substituting this into the ODE

$x^2 y_2'' + x y_2'+\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{4}\right)y_2$

$= x^2\left(-\dfrac{\cos (x) v'(x)}{x^{3/2}}-\dfrac{2 \sin (x) v'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{\cos (x) v''(x)}{\sqrt{x}}+\dfrac{v(x) \sin (x)}{x^{3/2}}+\dfrac{3 v(x) \cos (x)}{4 x^{5/2}}-\dfrac{v(x) \cos (x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right) + x \left(\dfrac{\cos (x) v'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}-\dfrac{v(x) \cos (x)}{2 x^{3/2}}-\dfrac{v(x) \sin (x)}{\sqrt{x}}\right) + \left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{4}\right)x^{-1/2} \cos(x) v(x) = 0$

Simplifying, we get

$$x^{3/2} \left(\cos (x) v''(x)-2 \sin (x) v'(x)\right) = 0$$

Now solve for $v(x)$ and then find $y_2(x)$.

Can you proceed?

The final result should be

$$y_2(x) = \dfrac{\cos (x) (c_1 \tan (x)+c_2)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

You can substitute this into $(1)$ and verify it satisfies the ODE.